# Closures inside nested do-while loops in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures, nested-loops

**Background**:
I'm writing UI tests in JavaScript, with Appium, for an iOS application. They have a similar structure such as [this example](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#using-the-standard-mocha).

**What am I trying to achieve**:
A test where the initial screen contains a list of elements ([UITableView in iOS](https://conceptdraw.com/a2621c3/p1/preview/640/pict--iphone-screen-template---settings---ringtone-settings---ringtone---template.png--diagram-flowchart-example.png)). From this list, I want to navigate some levels (don't know how many) deep till a condition is met. This should happen for the first 3 elements in that list (let's call it L0).

*Example*:
L0 (1st element) --> L1 --> L2 --> L3 --> L4 --> L5 --> condition met -> navigate back to L0
L0 (2nd element) --> L1 --> L2 --> condition met --> navigate back to L0
L0 (3rd element) --> L1 --> L2 --> L3 --> condition met --> navigate back to L0

**Show me the code**:

```
//the test
it('Browse list', function() {
    return driver
    .navigateToL0()
    .navigateToPageDetail(1, 3);
});

//the function with the issue
navigateToPageDetail: function(driver, startIndex, endIndex) {
    var listItemName;
    var navigationBarItemName;
    var hasListItemName = false;
    var navigationLevelCount = 0;
    var currentRootListElementIndex = startIndex;
    var currentListElementIndex = endIndex;
    var chain = driver;
    do {

      do {
        chain = chain
          .hasElementInListAtIndex(currentListElementIndex)
          .then(function(assertion) {
            hasListItemName = assertion;
            if (assertion == true) {
              return driver
                .getExpectedElementName(currentListElementIndex, function (name) {
                  listItemName = name;
                })
                .clickElementInListAtIndex(currentListElementIndex)
                .getActualElementName(function (name) {
                  navigationBarItemName = name;
                  listItemName.should.contain(navigationBarItemName);
                  navigationLevelCount ++;
                });
            }
            if (currentListElementIndex != 1) {
              currentListElementIndex = 1;
            }
          });
      } while (hasListItemName && (listItemName == navigationBarItemName));

      for (var j = 0; j <= navigationLevelCount; j++) {
        chain = chain.goBack();
      }
      currentRootListElementIndex++;
      currentListElementIndex = currentRootListElementIndex;

    } while  (currentRootListElementIndex <= endIndex);
    return chain;
}
```

**What's the problem?**

The inner `do while` runs only once, since the condition in that `while` is always false.
So `currentListElementIndex = 4` and then it navigates 3 times from L0 to L1 and back. (the 4th element in L0)

I understand that this is a problem with [closures inside loops](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#closures-inside-loops), but I don't understand how to fix my inner `do while` problem.

**What did you attempt?**

I attempted to use [Avoiding the Reference Problem](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#avoiding-the-reference-problem).
So my code becomes:

```
navigateToPageDetail: function(driver, startIndex, endIndex) {
    var listItemName;
    var navigationBarItemName;
    var hasListItemName = false;
    var navigationLevelCount = 0;
    var currentRootListElementIndex = startIndex;
    var currentListElementIndex = endIndex;
    var chain = driver;
    do {

      (function(currentListElementIndex_v2) {  //added line

      do {
        chain = chain
          .hasElementInListAtIndex(currentListElementIndex_v2)
          .then(function(assertion) {
            hasListItemName = assertion;
            if (assertion == true) {
              return driver
                .getExpectedElementName(currentListElementIndex_v2, function (name) {
                  listItemName = name;
                })
                .clickElementInListAtIndex(currentListElementIndex_v2)
                .getActualElementName(function (name) {
                  navigationBarItemName = name;
                  listItemName.should.contain(navigationBarItemName);
                  navigationLevelCount ++;
                });
            }
            if (currentListElementIndex_v2 != 1) {
              currentListElementIndex_v2 = 1;
            }
          });
      } while (hasListItemName && (listItemName == navigationBarItemName));

      })(currentListElementIndex);  //added line

      for (var j = 0; j <= navigationLevelCount; j++) {
        chain = chain.goBack();
      }
      currentRootListElementIndex++;
      currentListElementIndex = currentRootListElementIndex;

    } while  (currentRootListElementIndex <= endIndex);
    return chain;
}
```

That gets me closer to the expected behaviour, since `currentListElementIndex` gets the correct values now (1,2,3).
Still, the inner `do while` runs only once, since the condition in that `while` is always false.

**What's the question?**

How can I fix my code so that my inner `do while` loop runs as expected?
If something is not clear, please let me know and I'll improve the unclear parts.